# vb to c# Date related issue (DateAdd & DateInterval)

Tags: c#, vb.net

Greetings Everyone 
My issue is that i can't find a documentation for a part of this vb function

```
Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Today()), "yyyy")
```

I am not sure what this does but i need to change it to c#. 
I found something about `DateAdd` but i still can't figure how to convert this properly. 
I tried to seek for an interval in `DateTime` but nothing pops out

Comment: string date = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime.AddYears` method to change the year in a `DateTime`

```
string d = (DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)).ToString("yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.AddYears](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw8hzdwz(v=vs.110).aspx) function

You can do something like

```
var nowNextYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
var thisDateNextYear = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The datetime structure has some add methods that accept either positive or negative value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

If you absolutely need an interval, if I remember correctly subtracting 2 DateTime will give you a timespan. You can then use the AddTicks from the datetime with a the Timespan.ticks